# Java SimpleDateFormat issue with kk hour formatting

Tags: java, datetime, simpledateformat

I understand that kk is supposed to cause hours to range from 1-24. However, there seems to be an issue in how the days change in this formatting.

Here is example code and it's output to illustrate my point:

```
Long HOUR = 3600000L;

SimpleDateFormat kkFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd kk");
SimpleDateFormat HHFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH");

Date date = kkFormat.parse("2015-05-20 21");

for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
    System.out.println(kkFormat.format(new Date(date.getTime() + i * HOUR)));
    System.out.println(HHFormat.format(new Date(date.getTime() + i * HOUR)));
    System.out.println();
}
```

This generates the following output:

```
2015-05-20 21
2015-05-20 21

2015-05-20 22
2015-05-20 22

2015-05-20 23
2015-05-20 23

2015-05-21 24
2015-05-21 00

2015-05-21 01
2015-05-21 01
```

The issue that I see is with "2015-05-21 24" should this date not be formatted as "2015-05-20 24".

Thanks for clarifications.

edit: In answer to Dan Getz I'm trying to create file names that iterate as follows:

2015052023.txt

2015052024.txt

2015052101.txt

Comment: yes, but it's the last hour of day 20. Not the last hour of day 21. kk is supposed to iterate from 1 to 24, my interpretation of that is for a given day. Why should the day change from hour 23 to 24.

Comment: Thanks for editing more information into your question. Are you just trying to create some file names, or are these file names linked to time stamps, such as the time when the file is created, or events that will be recorded in the file? Is the "24th hour" supposed to be the start or end of a span of time?

Comment: The file names are indications of what information is contained within the file. Specifically, the files contain information for the hour ending n.

Comment: Did you find a good workaround for this? I have a similar issue where I want to display the last hour of the day as the 24th.

Comment: Hi Lisa, I ended up creating code that would generate a string and then alter it afterwards.. so.. pseudo code would be along the line of if (string.endsWith("00")) then cast position of the day into an int and increment by one OR (string.endsWith("24")) then cast position of the day into an int and decrement by one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What day it is, while dependent on time zone, is independent of the way the hours are written. So if the date is the 21st, then the date is the 21st, end of story. Writing "12am" as "00" or "24" is irrelevant to this.

Perhaps you're forgetting that an hour has 60 different minutes in it? It's not just about the first instant that the clock strikes midnight, it's the whole hour after that we're talking about, which is clearly part of the next 24-hour day.

I personally would never use 24 for times after 12am because of this ambiguity. Perhaps you could edit into your question why you'd want to use 24 as the hours for this? Is your data model truly time stamps down to the millisecond or similar? Or are you hoping to store and print something else?